# Is it possible that in the Local Interstellar Cloud there are undetected stars?

Tags: star

The Local Interstellar Cloud is supposed to be around 30 light years large. Is it possible that in this region there are stars which are undetected? I would have thought that it wasn't possible, but there are stars which are very small or are very close to another star. BTW, with star I mean an astronomical object which is performing fusion, because I've seen lists of smallest or coldest stars which includes brown dwarfs which don't perform fusion or white dwarfs.

Comment: "There are known unknowns and then there are unknown unknowns."   In this case, it's not only possible but almost a dead certainty.

Comment: Is there a blurry limit where you can be sure there arent undetected stars , due to gravitational forces effects, luminosity or whatever?

Comment: What is "the local interstellar cloud"?

Comment: According to a compatriot and colleague of yours,  a small low-density interstellar cloud where the sun is located https://www.centauri-dreams.org/2010/09/01/into-the-interstellar-void/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is unlikely, unless they are extremely faint. The reason is that the cloud obviously does not absorb enough light to keep us from detecting remote red and brown dwarfs, and hence a closer star would also be detectable.